# VoiceProcessingIO vs RemoteIO AudioUnit

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I have a VoIP app that uses a VoiceProcessingIO AudioUnit for call audio. In addition, there's a keypad in the app for pressing DTMF tones. I've written a small tone generator to play the standard sounds when the buttons are tapped.

The problem I have is:

1) If I use a RemoteIO AudioUnit, the AudioUnit initializes and starts fairly quickly, but sometimes stops working when there is an active call (I assume because of a conflict with the second VoiceProcessingIO audio unit)

2) If I use a VoiceProcessingIO AudioUnit, even with voice processing disabled, it takes too long for the AudioUnit to initialize and start, making it useless for playback on a button press (on an iPhone 7 it consistently takes ~40-60 ms for `AudioUnitInitialize` and `AudioOutputUnitStart` to return. However, it always works even when there's a call going on.

Am I doing something wrong here? RemoteIO seems closer to what I want for this audio unit - but is there a way to get it to consistently play even when the audio session is `AVAudioSessionPlayAndRecord` and there's a separate `VoiceProcessingIO` unit going on?

**Update:**

I may be wrong here. It looks as though the RemoteIO is playing with the VoiceProcessingIO unit, but it does so at a significantly lower volume than when the VoiceProcessingIO is not playing. It also seems to ignore the default output device (i.e. doesn't switch to speaker when I change the audio output device)

Comment: did you find out the reason? I am having similar problems with the volume of both IOs